# How do I segue to a new view controller after a short timeout?

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard

I want to show the user a title screen of the app name firstly and then, after about 2 seconds, the view should proceed to a new view controller.

So far, I have a segue with an identifier. I see a lot of tutorials use `IBAction`s/`IBOutlet`s but I'm not sure if I would use one here since there's no single item that would trigger the segue aside from the timeout.

Comment: Don't do any of this. Users want to use your app, not stare at some title screen. This goes against Apple's Human Interface Guidelines. See their discussion about the [Launch Screen](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/launch-screen/).

Comment: @rmaddy This can be true, but some applications (especially games) still do this. Moreover, even the official Twitter app uses a little animation in the beginning before the user interaction is enabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline:)` in `viewDidLoad`. This code triggers the segue with the given identifier after a 2 seconds delay:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "your segue's identifier", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: Cool, and I don't have to add an IB object of any sort to this?

Comment: @baruma No, it's not needed.

Comment: Well, I got this error after trying it out.  Here's what I have :

Comment: I have an "expected declaration error" that pops up when I incorporate this code into the VC that's supposed to have the segue performed.

Comment: Oh wow, that was it.  Thanks it worked!  I just don't understand the logic behind this piece of code and why it would be put in the viewdidload func

Comment: @baruma `viewDidLoad` runs after a particular view has been loaded. This block performs the functions inside it after a 2 second delay. Learn more about `UIViewController`s and their lifecycles [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller).